# How to add a comment to an opportunity?

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to update/attach the activity comment with the opportunity comment.

```
trigger trgTaskComment on Task (before insert) {
     Task[] Comment = Trigger.new;
    for (Task newActivity : Trigger.new) //we have to create a comment section
        {
            //if task.whatid.left(3)=='006'
            //Opportunity opp = [Select Id, Description from Opportunity where Id=:task.whatid];
            //opp.Description=task.Comment;
            //update opp;
```

Comment: What issue are you encountering with your code? You definitely need to bulkify this by accumulating your opportunity Ids in a set or map and querying in a batch, but you seem to have an idea of how to accomplish this.

Comment: I do, but I don't actually know how i should start this

Comment: The code you have commented out is a good start. I recommend reviewing the Trailhead on [bulkifying triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_bulk) so that you don't try to put SOQL or DML in a loop. Then ask when you need specific guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you pretty close:

```
trigger trgTaskComment on Task (before insert) {
    Map<Id, Task> oppsToTasks = new Map<Id, Task>();
    List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

    for (Task t : Trigger.New) {
        if (t.whatId.left == '006') {
            oppsToTasks.put(t.whatId, t);
        }
    }

    for (Opportunity o : [
        SELECT Description
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Id IN :oppsToTasks.keySet();
    ]) {
        o.description = oppsToTasks.get(o.Id).comment;
        oppsToUpdate.add(o);
    }

    if (!oppsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        update oppsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

As several people have pointed out in the comments. You need to [bulkify](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kBjYIAU) your code. Your trigger runs on ALL records that update at the same time so if 200 records update at once, your code needs to be able to support that. Never have a query within a loop as that is the fastest/easiest way to violate the [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). (If you have 101 tasks, you will query 101 opps, which will result in violating the SOQL limits).